# How do I define the min value of a progress bar in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make a progress bar from -51 to -113.

How can I do so using javascript or jquery. So far I can only set the max value of the progress bar.

```
<progress value="-75" max="-51"></progress>
```

UPDATE: Changed value to a valid value. Sorry

Comment: Post your code here... What progress bar you using ? Is that bootstrap or any thing else?

Comment: What have you tried, and why doesn't the documentation for your progressbar help?

Comment: And how did you set your max value on progress bar ?

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar check his code he mention as max="-51"

Comment: How can your value be -30 if the max is -51 ???

Comment: I hope you can't set the value as value="-31" in negative then it wont so any progress...

Comment: Its a progress bar it want to show its process from start to how much it completed? In this why you need to set a min value? Unnecessary.

Comment: Hey still the same you i hope you can't force a progress to min by externally

Answer (score 2):

You can't represent negative values with `<progress>`
Instead you should use `<meter>` :

```
<meter min="-113" value="-70" max="-51"></meter>
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/g7J8F/

Comment: Note: The meter tag is not supported in Internet Explorer or Safari 5 (and earlier versions).

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle with `meter` tag demo.

Comment: @singe31 as because IE is most of default browser in many people's machine

Comment: @AntoKing Of course you need IE to download a real browser

Comment: @singe31 hahaha really.... a good pic regarding this went viral once in FB, and i deal with the clients who is not ready to download anything else than IE. As for client satisfaction we use to do most check with IE

Comment: @singe31 1. IE isn't as bad anymore as its reputation is, so don't just repeat what everyone says. 2. It's mostly used in companys due to security issues.

Answer (score 1):

----to get or set Minimum values----

Set the min property.

```
$('#jqxProgressBar').jqxProgressBar({ min: 10 });
```

Get the min property.

```
var min = $('#jqxProgressBar').jqxProgressBar('min');
```

----to get or set Maximum values----

Set the max property.

```
$('#jqxProgressBar').jqxProgressBar({  max: 150 });
```

Get the max property.

```
var max = $('#jqxProgressBar').jqxProgressBar('max');
```

check this website for more information

http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/jqxprogressbar/jquery-progressbar-api.htm

Comment: Since your answer uses a plugin not distributed with jQuery, you should point that out. Something like "You can use the jqx plugin for that, see (URL) for installation instructions" is enough, but a short description of why you recommend it is even better.

Answer (score 0):

Just make its max 62, substract 113 if you get the progressbars value and add 113 when you set it.

Answer (score 0):

Using Jquery Set min value and max value in Progress

`   $("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: parseFloat($('#hdn_Viewbaguserspace').val()) });

```
$("#progressbar").progressbar("option", "max", parseFloat($('#hdn_viewbagtotalspace').val()));`
```